# Adding code to an existing thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Given a thread (that is not dead):

```
t = Thread.new{sleep}
```

is it possible to add some code, given as a proc for example, and run that within `t`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps by using a thread variable and waiting until it's defined:

```
a = Thread.new do
  while Thread.current["proc"].nil?
    sleep 0.5
    puts "Next round.."
  end
  Thread.current["proc"].call
end

sleep 3

a["proc"] = Proc.new { puts "hello there!" }

a.join
```

Which will output:

```
Next round..
Next round..
Next round..
Next round..
Next round..
Next round..
hello there!
```

But if you're asking if you can break the Thread.new {sleep} from sleeping and inserting something else for it to run, I don't know, maybe by using thread.raise :

```
class ExceptionWithProc < StandardError
  attr_accessor :proc
end

a = Thread.new {sleep rescue $!.proc.call}

exception = ExceptionWithProc.new
exception.proc = Proc.new { puts "hello there!" }

sleep 3

a.raise(exception)
a.join
```

Comment: The added part of your answer is wrong. `t = Thread.new{sleep}`
gives `#<Thread:0x007f76884a22b0 sleep>`.Then
`t.instance_eval{puts Thread.current}` gives
`# => #<Thread:0x007f768812b460>` and
`t.instance_exec{puts Thread.current}` gives
`# => #<Thread:0x007f768812b460>`.

Comment: Yeah looks like it's not executed inside the actual thread but inside the thread instance just like `a = String.new; a.instance_exec..`

Comment: I think you could use something like `a.raise Something` and have a `rescue $!.proc.call` after your `sleep` that calls a proc passed along the exception.

Comment: Well that is kind of hairy :) Most likely not the best way to accomplish what you're trying to do, I bet the problem you're solving has been solved elsewhere, take a look in for example the Celluloid gem in http://celluloid.io or https://github.com/jdantonio/concurrent-ruby